# Meter contenido de input en variable

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito que el texto que añada en un input y el numero que añada en otro se guarden en variables diferentes, he probado diferentes métodos pero ninguno me funciona, (para comprobar si funciona llamo a un alert) y, o me aparece [object HTMLInputElement], o me aparece null o me aparece en blanco el alert

```
Añade dato
<input type="text" name="agregarDato" id="addFact"><br><br>
Escribe valor
<input type="number" name="agregarValor" id="addValue"><br><br>
Escribe valor extra
<input type="number" name="agregarValorextra" id="addExtraValue"><br><br>
<button id="addAll">Añadir</button>
```

```
function inicio() {
    //Recoger los datos de los input
    let empresa = document.getElementById("addFact").value;
    let valor1 = document.getElementById("addValue").value;
    let valorExt = document.getElementById("addExtraValue").value;
    let enviar = document.getElementById("addAll");

    //Cargar datos al presionar boton de enviar
    enviar.onclick = function (e) {
        alert(empresa + " " + valor1 + " " + valorExt);
    }
}
```

Con el codigo que he compartido al ejecutarse el alert aparece en blanco.

Comment: Deberías obtener los valores dentro del evento, porque los asignas antes de que se hayan modificado.

Comment: ```
let empresa;
let valor1;
let valorExt;
let enviar = document.getElementById("addAll");

enviar.onclick = function (e) {
        empresa = document.getElementById("addFact").value;
        valor1 = document.getElementById("addValue").value;
        valorExt = document.getElementById("addExtraValue").value;

        alert(empresa + " " + valor1 + " " + valorExt)
}
```
Algo asi??

Comment: Aunque no se ve muy bien, perdon por eso... en los comentarios no se puede poner salto de linea

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta para actualizar el código. Parece más o menos correcto, pruébalo y nos cuentas.

Comment: Lo actualizaria pero estoy completamente atascado asi que no puedo, lo siento

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo siguiente

```js
function inicio() {
    //Recoger los datos de los input
     empresa = $("#addFact").val();
     valor1 = $("#addValue").val();
     valorExt = $("#addExtraValue").val();
    
alert(empresa + " " + valor1 + " " + valorExt);
   console.log(empresa + " " + valor1 + " " + valorExt);
   
}

 //Cargar datos al presionar boton de enviar
$("#addAll").click(function() {
   inicio();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Añade dato
<input type="text" name="agregarDato" id="addFact"><br><br>
Escribe valor
<input type="number" name="agregarValor" id="addValue"><br><br>
Escribe valor extra
<input type="number" name="agregarValorextra" id="addExtraValue"><br><br>
<button id="addAll">Añadir</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Cuando creas la variable tenes que sacarle el .value y añadirlo cuando queres tomar el valor.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="agregarDato" /><br /><br />
        Escribe valor
        <input type="number" class="agregarValor" /><br /><br />
        Escribe valor extra
        <input type="number" class="agregarValorextra" /><br /><br />
        <button class="addAll" type="submit">Añadir</button>

        <script src="codigo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

codigo.js

```
let agregarDato = document.querySelector(".agregarDato");
let agregarValor = document.querySelector(".agregarValor");
let agregarValorextra = document.querySelector(".agregarValorextra");
let addAll = document.querySelector(".addAll");

addAll.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert(
        "agregar Dato: " +
            agregarDato.value +
            " agregar Valor: " +
            agregarValor.value +
            " agregar Valor extra: " +
            agregarValorextra.value
    );
});
```

te dejo el enlace a codepen: https://codepen.io/matimagallanes/pen/XWNWWRr

Comment: @andres martinez, una duda... que es y para que se utiliza val(), lo digo mas que nada para no poner en mi codigo algo que no entiendo como funciona